# How to get list from List<Pair> in Android

Tags: android, list, kotlin, kotlin-flow

In my application I want `combine` two deferent lists and for this I used `kotlin flow` and `combine` & `zip` operators!
I write below codes, but when used in activity I don't know how can I get lists!

**ViewModel codes :**

```
class ViewModel (private val repository: Repository) : ViewModel() {

    val moviesFlow = repository.moviesList()
    val genresFlow = repository.genresList()

    fun loadData(): Flow<List<Pair<MoviesResponse.Data, GenresList>>> =
        combine(moviesFlow, genresFlow) { movieList: Response<MoviesResponse>,
                                          genreList: Response<GenresList> ->
            val movies = movieList.body()?.data
            val genres = genreList.body()!!
            return@combine movies?.zip(genres)!!
        }
}
```

**Activity codes :**

```
    lifecycleScope.launchWhenCreated {
        viewModel.loadData().collect {
            
        }
    }
```

I want get each on lists and set into `adapter`!

When write **it** into `collect`, say me select index such as : **it[0]**

But I want get each lists and set into `recycler adapter`.

How can I it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you question correctly, you want to convert "list of pairs" to "pair of lists". You can use the `unzip` function for this.

```kotlin
viewModel.loadData().collect {
    val (movies, genres) = it.unzip()
}
```

Here, `movies` will be the list of movies from `moviesFlow` and `genres` will
be the list of genres from `genresFlow`.

But if you only wanted these two lists separately, you could have collected the two flows in the `Activity` directly instead of first zipping and then unzipping.

Comment: Yes my friend, your answer is help me. thanks my friend ❤